# "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s" 2Checkout payment API

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, 2checkout

i have integrate 2Checkout Payment API using following code but got error when Authorize Customer.

follow : https://www.2checkout.com/documentation/libraries-net-tutorial

Code :

```
 public ActionResult Process()
 {
       TwoCheckoutConfig.SellerID = "801785575";
       TwoCheckoutConfig.PrivateKey = "SA7947DS-CWE1-1233-4EE-33331DA607B6";
       TwoCheckoutConfig.Sandbox = true;

       try
       {
          var Billing = new AuthBillingAddress();
          Billing.addrLine1 = "123 test st";
          Billing.city = "Columbus";
          Billing.zipCode = "43123";
          Billing.state = "OH";
          Billing.country = "USA";
          Billing.name = "Testing Tester";
          Billing.email = "example@2co.com";

          var Customer = new ChargeAuthorizeServiceOptions();
          Customer.total = (decimal)1.00;
          Customer.currency = "USD";
          Customer.merchantOrderId = "123";
          Customer.billingAddr = Billing;
          Customer.token = Request["token"];

          var Charge = new ChargeService();

          var result = Charge.Authorize(Customer);
          Console.Write(result);
       }
       catch (TwoCheckoutException e)
       {
          Console.Write(e);
       }

       return View();
}
```

Got Error "Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s" 
Please help me..

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace I got when the error reproduced, the exception seems originated from [`System.IO.StringReader(String s)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.stringreader(v=vs.110).aspx) constructor since certain action passed the constructor argument as null string value, indicating you're using a version of `TwoCheckOut` DLL assembly which may having bug with `StringReader` that expects non-null value (it belongs to the `TwoCheckOut` assembly).

Try updating `TwoCheckOut` assembly by issuing Package Manager command:

```
Update-Package TwoCheckout
```

If the update process is unsuccessful or the exception still appears after updating, remove the corresponding package with this command:

```
Uninstall-Package TwoCheckout
```

Then download latest `TwoCheckOut` DLL assembly from [this source](https://github.com/2Checkout/2checkout-dotnet) and add it in `References` section of your project.

Similar issues:

[Value cannot be null. Parameter name: s, 2Chekout sandbox error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34059593/value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name-s-2chekout-sandbox-error)

[TwoCheckout System.ArgumentNullException : Value cannot be null Parameter name: s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36640280/twocheckout-system-argumentnullexception-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name)

Comment: thank you for reply but where can i found updated TwoCheckOut.dll. i have apply dll from here https://github.com/2Checkout/2checkout-dotnet

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded the [TwoCheckout source code](https://github.com/2Checkout/2checkout-dotnet/tree/master/TwoCheckout) and added it as an Existing Project to my Solution. Then I added the project as a Reference for my main project and it worked just fine for me.